# Python failing to compile on Linux with custom module built in

Tags: python, gcc, makefile, python-2.6

I am trying to compile Python 2.6.7 with a custom module built in but I am running into problems. Everything is going fine until the linker tries to link the dependencies that my module has. The make file gets generated just fine and the path were the libraries are installed to is correct. The way I configured Python to compile with my custom module is like so:

```
_myplugin _myplugin.c++ -I/home/me/Desktop/Depends/include -L/home/me/Desktop/Depends/lib -l libcrvs_pic.a -l libsb_pic.a -l liblmgr_dongle_stup_pic.a
```

The build fails on this line:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcrvs_pic.a
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is specify the libraries without the `lib` prefix, and also without the `.a` suffix.

Like so:

```
-lcrvs_pic
```